# How can I fill in missing SQL rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:
DDates

| date |
| --- |
| 05.01.2022 |
| 04.01.2022 |
| 03.01.2022 |
| 02.01.2022 |
| 01.01.2022 |

Currancy:

| date | curr | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05.10.2022 | USD | 12 |
| 04.10.2022 | USD | NULL |
| 03.10.2022 | EUR | 11 |
| 01.10.2022 | USD | 10 |
| 05.10.2022 | EUR | 13 |
| 04.10.2022 | EUR | 14 |
| 01.10.2022 | EUR | 13 |

How can I get result like this?

| date | curr | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05.10.2022 | USD | 12 |
| 04.10.2022 | USD | 11 |
| 03.10.2022 | USD | 11 |
| 02.10.2022 | USD | 11 |
| 01.10.2022 | USD | 10 |
| 05.10.2022 | EUR | 13 |
| 04.10.2022 | EUR | 14 |
| 03.10.2022 | EUR | 13 |
| 02.10.2022 | EUR | 13 |
| 01.10.2022 | EUR | 13 |

I guess I should use LAG function, but it's not working.

The current attempt is

```
SELECT t.ddate,
       COALESCE(c.curr,LAG(c.curr) OVER(PARTITION BY c.curr ORDER BY c.ddate))
  FROM ddate t
  LEFT JOIN Currancy c
    ON t.ddate = c.ddate
 ORDER BY c.curr, c.ddate DESC;
```

Comment: Can you share the description of what you're trying to accomplish and your attempt with the LAG function?

Comment: SELECT t.ddate,
coalesce(c.curr, LAG(c.curr)  OVER(partition by c.curr ORDER BY c.ddate))
FROM ddate t 
left join Currancy c on t.ddate=c.ddate
order by c.curr, c.ddate desc;

Comment: It should be **Currency** (not "currancy" .....) if you're talking about money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a partitioned outer join and then get the latest value with the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT d."DATE",
       c.curr,
       LAST_VALUE(c.rate) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY c.curr ORDER BY d."DATE")
         AS rate
FROM   ddates d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN currancy c
       PARTITION BY (c.curr)
       ON (d."DATE" = c."DATE");
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DDates ("DATE") AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Currancy ("DATE", curr, rate) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-05', 'USD', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-04', 'USD', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-03', 'EUR', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', 'USD', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-05', 'EUR', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-04', 'EUR', 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', 'EUR', 13 FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| DATE | CURR | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | EUR | 13 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | EUR | 13 |
| 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | EUR | 11 |
| 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | EUR | 14 |
| 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | EUR | 13 |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | USD | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | USD | 10 |
| 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | USD | 10 |
| 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | USD | 10 |
| 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | USD | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E0ZZ6o9r)